# Reverse complementing column of DNA sequences

Tags: r, regex

Let's say I have 1 column and n rows worth of DNA sequences in R. I need to replace the each element in the column with each elements' reverse complement. What is the best way to proceed?

Comment: Try with `chartr` i.e. `chartr('ACGT', 'TGCA', 'AAAGGGCTAAG')`

Answer (score 2):

Use `Biostrings::reverseComplement`:

```
# Sample data
set.seed(2017);
df <- cbind.data.frame(
    DNA = sapply(sample(5:25), function(x)
        paste(sample(c("A", "C", "T", "G"), x, replace = TRUE), collapse = ""))
);

require(Biostrings);
df$revComp <- sapply(df$DNA, function(x) as.character(reverseComplement(DNAString(x))));
head(df);
#                       DNA                  revComp
#1 CGGAGTCACGACAGTAAATTTAAG CTTAAATTTACTGTCGTGACTCCG
#2          TATGGTGCTTCAGTG          CACTGAAGCACCATA
#3            ACTGTCAATTGTA            TACAATTGACAGT
#4               GGCCTCGAGT               ACTCGAGGCC
#5       GAAAACAGTTTGAGAGAG       CTCTCTCAAACTGTTTTC
#6        GAATACTAAAAGAGTCA        TGACTCTTTTAGTATTC
```